# Is there a Unix / Linux command to count lines per second from stdin?

Tags: linux, performance

I am trying to count the number of SQL queries per second from a log file and I want to do it in real time by pipeing stdout from grep into some command.  ( I am doing some performance testing )

I could write it myself, but thought for sure this would exist.

I looked at wc but didn't see an option to allow this.

I could also use it to count requests per second by piping a tail from the access log.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754470/mysql-count-how-many-queries-per-second-are-executed-is-there-any-way

Comment: I am looking for something more generally useful that what that question refers to.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[`pv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) is your command! **P**ipe **V**iewer prints stats about the data passing through it, and can run anywhere in your pipeline, since it pipes stdin directly over to stdout. For example:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log | pv --line-mode --rate > /dev/null
```

The `pv` command prints to stderr the current number of lines per second (the default is bytes per second), which, for this particular data source (Nginx's default log file), equates to incoming web requests per second. I only care about the counts, so I pipe stdout into `/dev/null`. There are also options like:

- `-b` (total number of lines),
- `--average-rate` (average rate since starting), and
- `--timer` (tracks how long the pipe has been going).

If you don't say `--line-mode`, it'll count bytes, which is probably not what you want for server logs, but could be handy elsewhere.

Final note: `... | pv -lb > file.txt` is a lot like `... | tee file.txt | awk '{printf "\r%lu", NR}'`, which is also handy for counting lines, but the `pv` call is way shorter, though the output is not quite as exciting — `pv` updates every second by default, while that `awk` command updates continuously.

Comment: Is it possible to get only one value from pv? I need average value for time period for monitoring purpose. So i need to assign value to variable.

Comment: @Sonique it's a kludge, since that's not what `pv` is built for (I'd reach for `awk` if I were you), but of course it's possible. Suppose `twilight stream --timeout 5` is a command that will sample from the Twitter spritzer for 5 seconds and then quit: `RATE="$(twilight stream --timeout 5 | pv --line-mode --rate --force 2>&1 1>/dev/null | tr -s '\r\n' '\n' | tail -1)"`, then `echo $RATE` produces something like "[40.8 /s]" (note the additional `--force` flag, since `pv`'s `stderr` is no longer a TTY).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work reliably for me for all programs; removing the `> /dev/null` shows that the output is now "block chunked" and no longer streams smoothly. Perhaps `unbuffer` is needed on some producing programs so that they don't switch to block output buffering when they detect that they're being piped?

Answer (score 16):

Maybe you should try `logtop` ?

```
tail -f foobar.log |logtop
```

Comment: Is this the log top you are referring to?  https://github.com/JulienPalard/logtop/

Comment: Yes, if you are using debian there is a package in repository http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/logtop

Comment: dang I think this is what I need but I couldn't get it to compile on CentOs

Answer (score 3):

```
watch -n 3 "wc -l logfile"
```

man page

watch - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen
By default, the program is run every 2 seconds; use -n or --interval to specify a different interval.

Comment: Good reminder about `watch`, but this approach doesn't really count queries (lines written) per second as requested. Instead, it counts the total lines present in the log file every second.

Answer (score 1):

```
watch -n 5 "mysqladmin status | awk -F'  ' '{ print \$NF }'"
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work.  You sure about the syntax?

Comment: Which error do you get? Have you configured `~/.my.cnf` to run `mysqladmin` without prompting for password?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a system where you can't install `pv` or `logtop` suggested above, and the log file is too large to read the whole thing with `wc`, you can tail-watch it instead:

```
MYLOGS=$(timeout 10 tail -f /path/to/log.log)
expr $(echo "$MYLOGS" | wc -l) / 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, some of the tools given in these answers are not installed by default in most of the Linux distos.

Here is a piece of command line that should work everytime (Perl is almost everywhere)

```
tail -f /var/log/some_logfile.log | perl -e 'while (<>) {$l++;if (time > $e) {$e=time;print "$l\n";$l=0}}'
```